# Android R-file error

Tags: android

When I import some source code, eclipse throws me many errors about R-file for example :

1)`R.string.pref_default_time_from_now_key;`

2)`R.xml.task_preferences;`

3)`R.id.body;`

4)`R.id.reminder_time;`

5)`R.id.reminder_date;`

Eclipse asks me to import R file but I do not need that, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: check if you have any errors in your resource files. fix it. clean and build

Comment: There are no errors in resource file, when I import R-file it doesn't read id's and xml files.

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid check if you have R.java generated. If not you will probably have errors in your resource files.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you do not import another R.java from another class.
- Make sure all your resources are named correctly (small letters, digits and underscores only)
- Try cleaning the project